# CSS @import only for Retina display

Tags: css, media-queries, retina-display

I have an `@import` at the top of my main.css file that pulls in retina.css for my retina-specific styles.

Are there media queries I can add to `@import` to show the retina.css file *only* on retina devices? I don't want retina.css to load on every page/every device, and I want to keep the retina styles in a separate file.

```
@import "retina-styles.css";

/*** other styles below ***/
```

I can't use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="retina.css" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />` in the `<head>` because the developers want to use `@import`.

Comment: Why do the developers want to use an `@import` statement? Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't it function exactly like a `<link />` tag?

Comment: They're building a web app with many pages and if we add new CSS files or change file names, they'd rather change one css file with the @imports in it than update every page.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Well-structured webapps usually have a global `<head>` section that's imported by all pages through serverside code.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered why they didn't go that route. I'm just designing this round though, so it's up to them! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MDN "@import"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%40import) it is possible to use media queries in `@import`-statements:

```
@import url;
@import url list-of-media-queries;
```

So this one should work (untested):

```
@import url(retina.css) screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2);
```

You can read more about the `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`-property in the Apple's Safari Developer Library: "[Supported CSS Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safaricssref/Articles/OtherStandardCSS3Features.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007601-SW1)"

Answer (score -1):

You can just wrap all your retina styles in a media query using the min-device-pixel-ratio then just @import the file into your existing css at the bottom. Or just include the styles into the main css with the same media query wrapped around them.

Comment: I wanted to see if it could be done with `@import` rather than wrapping the CSS in media queries so the retina.css file doesn't load on non-retina devices. Also, I'm pretty sure `@import` can only be at the top.